# mediaquery.of() called with a context that does not contain a media query.No media query could be found starting from the context

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Hi I could not resolve this error  Exception has occurred. FlutterError (MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery. No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have a Widgets App or Material App widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets. The context used was: Scaffold)

Here is the code:

```html
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(HomePage());
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  gotoSecondActivity(BuildContext context){
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondActivity()),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
      child:Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
              );
              gotoSecondActivity(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill
                        )
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FadeAnimation(1.8, Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                    blurRadius: 20.0,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 10)
                                )
                              ]
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey[100]))
                                ),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller:emailController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[400])
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: passwordController,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[400])
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                        SizedBox(height: 30,),
                        FadeAnimation(2, Container(
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                  ]
                              )
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Login", style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          ),
                        )),
                        SizedBox(height: 70,),
                        FadeAnimation(1.5, Text("Forgot Password?",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by using the below steps,

Yes the MediaQuery.of(context)--> is from on the MaterialApp and WidgetApp only

Step 1:

```
void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Step 2:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MediaQuery',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Step 3:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  gotoSecondActivity(BuildContext context){
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              gotoSecondActivity(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(child:  Text('hello'),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your Code :

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return MultiProvider(
```

Just Correct this .it will work